# How to use Windows Active Directory Server Publically

Tags: windows-server-2008

Hi i have a windows server 2008 which has a public ip i wish to connect all my employees Laptops on the network of that server but couldn't find any doc relevant to that !!

Comment: This is a terrible idea. I'd reconsider your architecture.

Comment: I'm 23. I've been working with AD for the past 4 years and I still have a lot to learn but please understand that this is NOT the right way to do it. A managed service or a sysadmin will be expensive, but nothing compared to the costs of hacked servers and lawsuits by customers (you've not said what the company does, sorry).

Comment: By the way, if you *are* looking for someone to help on the systems admin side of things on an as-needed basis, I'm available on an evening or weekend basis for project work. My email address is in my profile if you'd like to discuss rates for this.

Answer (score 4):

No. No no no no no.

Keep your domain controllers private (behind a firewall) and use a VPN if you want then to have access to your internal environment.

Comment: But thing is i want them to connect it with my laptop and my employees laptops

Comment: So set up a VPN for the remote users.

Comment: I am new to windows can you guide me for this thank you very much

Comment: Sorry. That's not what this site it for. If you have a technical question that you need a specific answer for, I'd be more than happy to answer it. No one is going to architect an entire directory services/VPN solution for you for free, though. You need to have your employer send you to classes or get some training material.

Comment: yeah man if you had read my last sentence  asked about a guide not a not a solution on this site!!

Comment: There's no "guide" for this kind of thing. How you set it up depends on your needs and your needs depend on your user requirements and your existing architecture. Really you're in over your head. Consider hiring a consultant. I'm not trying to be mean, but this is a site for professionals acting in a professional capacity. Not exposing a DC to the outside world is such an incredibly basic thing that it seems like you really have no fundamental knowledge of how this works. Do your employer a favor and admit that you need help before you make a terrible mess.

Comment: The only sensible 'guide' for what you're doing will be one line long and it will say "Don't do this. No, really. We're serious. Guide over."